# I/O redirection differences between zsh and bash

Tags: bash, shell, terminal, zsh, io-redirection

I use zsh at the command-line but the shell scripts I write run bash so that they are portable.

I was learning about IO redirection from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16283739/340947) when I realized this difference:

Note that the command is just an arbitrary one whose first line of output is over stderr and the second line comes over stdout.

`zsh` on OS X:

```
% ls -ld /tmp /tnt 1>&2 2>&1  | sed -e 's/^/++/'
ls: /tnt: No such file or directory
++ls: /tnt: No such file or directory
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Oct 19  2012 /tmp -> private/tmp
++lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Oct 19  2012 /tmp -> private/tmp
```

`bash`:

```
bash-3.2$ ls -ld /tmp /tnt 1>&2 2>&1  | sed -e 's/^/++/'
ls: /tnt: No such file or directory
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Oct 19  2012 /tmp -> private/tmp
```

I'm having a hard time figuring out `zsh`'s output.

Also, on a Linux the output order's slightly different for `zsh`:

```
% ls -ld /tmp /tnt 1>&2 2>&1  | sed -e 's/^/++/'
ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
drwxrwxrwt. 13 root root 4096 Dec 19 23:11 /tmp
++ls: cannot access /tnt: No such file or directory
++drwxrwxrwt. 13 root root 4096 Dec 19 23:11 /tmp
```

`bash` output is identical though.

More experimentation in `zsh`:

```
% ls -ld /tmp /tnt 1>&2 | sed -e 's/^/++/'
ls: /tnt: No such file or directory
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Oct 19  2012 /tmp -> private/tmp
++lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Oct 19  2012 /tmp -> private/tmp

% ls -ld /tmp /tnt 2>&1 | sed -e 's/^/++/'
++ls: /tnt: No such file or directory
++lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Oct 19  2012 /tmp -> private/tmp
```

That last one there produces identical results to `bash`.

I figure I should prefer learning `bash`'s behavior inside-out before delving into how `zsh` ticks, but this isn't really ideal because chances are at least half of the IO redirection I expect to be doing will be spur-of-the-moment hacks that I surely will want to try from the `zsh` prompt. And I'm actually pretty invested in `zsh` because I have a ton of custom plugins and it would be a major effort at this point to do a big switch back to bash.

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing two levels of output redirect, just use `2>&1` and it should be the same in both... or, is there a reason for using `1>&2`?

Comment: It is just to explore why they behave differently. Yes, this is a toy example. I am not asking this question to "get something done" per se, I am asking it to gain a better understanding so that I can understand and explain how this works so that I can later use the power of knowledge to get many things done.

Comment: And to answer your question specifically... `1>&2` is supposed to send stdout to stderr (which is the terminal), but zsh appears to still be sending a copy of it into the pipe as well.

Comment: It does exactly that... you can't both redirect stdout to stderr (and stderr to stdout)... I'm not surprised bash and zsh interpret that impossibility differently.

Comment: Yes you can because bash defines the order in which redirections are applied and the results are consistent and logical. I have demonstrated where zsh deviates from this, the question is what specifically is different in its behavior?

Comment: "Portable" usually means sticking to the POSIX standard. A script using `bash` features still requires `bash`, regardless of how widely deployed `bash` may be. A POSIX-compliant script will (ok, should) run unmodified in any POSIX-compliant shell: `bash`, `dash`, `ksh`, `zsh`, etc.

Comment: See http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's due to `zsh`'s [mult_ios feature](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios).

In `zsh`, when a fd is redirected twice, `zsh` implements an internal `tee`:

```
ls > foo > bar
```

Sends the output of `ls` to a pipe and `zsh` feeds it to both `foo` and `bar`.

It can get confusing with pipes.

```
ls > foo | cmd
```

Sends the output to both `foo` and `cmd`.

You can disable it with:

```
setopt no_mult_ios
```

Comment: Fantastic, `zsh` kicks some ass, as it turns out