# Redirection and pipe behavior in bash vs. zsh

Tags: bash, shell, pipe, zsh, io-redirection

The following command outputs different results depending if it is run in bash or zsh:

```
ls -l > x | wc -l
```

If executed in a non-empty directory, bash always gives 0, while zsh gives the right number of files. *x* contains the output of `ls -l`, as expected.

Why doesn't it work in bash?

Comment: The only way zsh could make that work would be to play `tee` (reading the output from `ls -l` itself, and writing it twice, once to the file, and once to `wc -l`). That's... a rather intrusive and unusual feature for a shell to provide, as opposed to connecting `ls -l` *directly* to either the file `x` or the stdin of `wc -l`, and not having any hand in touching the content being processed.

Comment: One portable way to write this would be `ls -l | tee x | wc -l`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Read the [MULTIOS documentation](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Redirection.html#Multios) in the `zshmisc` man page. It's a feature of zsh which causes it to redirect the output to multiple files at the same time, and it can also be a pipe.

e.g.

```
ls >a >b
```

will get both `a` and `b` populated with the content of the directory.

from the `zshmisc` documentation:

> If the user tries to open a file descriptor for writing more than once, the shell opens the file descriptor as a pipe to a process that copies its input to all the specified outputs,  similar  to  tee, provided the MULTIOS option is set, as it is by default.  Thus:

```
date >foo >bar
```

> writes the date to two files, named `foo` and `bar`.  Note that a pipe is an implicit redirection; thus

```
date >foo | cat
```

> writes the date to the file `foo`, and also pipes it to cat.

To turn it on you do `setopt multios`, to turn off you do `setopt nomultios`:

```
$ setopt nomultios
$ ls -l > x | wc -l
0
$ setopt multios
$ ls -l > x | wc -l
36
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually stumbled upon [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20735659/3997816) that explained it too.

Answer (score 4):

The output from `ls -l` is redirected into a file called 'x'.  There is no output to go into the pipe (it's all going into 'x').  This is the way most every standard shell works.

The question here isn't why bash doesn't work, the question is why does zsh do what it does.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.

Comment: @bitoiu This is an answer to this question, isn't it? I don't see a new question here.